# How to override @Autowired with XML

Tags: java, spring, autowired, inject, oval

In a Spring project I am trying to get injection to work in OVal (a SourceForge library) custom validators (CheckWith implementations). The OVal injector contains roughtly:

```
public class SpringInjector {
    @Autowired
    private AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor processor;
}
```

and according to the OVal documentation is supposed to be declared this way: `<bean class="net.sf.oval.integration.spring.SpringInjector" />`. 
The problem is that there are already 3 candidates for injection. Is there a way to override the `@Autowire` in the XML config given that the `processor` variable has no accessor methods? Or any other way to get injection to work in OVal custom validators?

Comment: According to the [docs](http://oval.sourceforge.net/userguide.html#spring-integration), which you are probably quoting, OVal & Spring can be easily integrated. However at this point I fail to properly understand your problem. If you simply need to chose one of multiple similar beans you could mark it as primary with `<bean ... primary="true|false"/>` but I'd like to know which `3 candidates` we are talking about in your scenario. Can you share your spring configuration and any error message you may be getting?

Answer (score 0):

Add this:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor"/>
<bean class="net.sf.oval.integration.spring.SpringInjector"/>
```